# ¿Cómo diseñar contenido de pestañas por separado para posteriormente llamarlas al windows form principal?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy inciando una aplicación de escritorio en `windows forms`, quiero hacer un diseño de panel de control de administrador, por lo que cada "pestaña" tendrá un contenido diferente. Pero no puedo diseñar todas las pestañas en el mismo formulario ya que se amontonaría y sería dificil de trabajarlo. No sé si exista una manera en la que por aparte pueda diseñar el contendido para cada pestaña y solamente mandar llamar el respectivo contendio de la pestaña que haya sido presionada.
Este sería el formulario principal:

[image]

Encontré algo que se llama `UserControl` en el que puede diseñar con elementos de `Windows forms`, pero no estoy seguro si ese es el idicado para lograr lo que quiero, ya que tampoco sé como mandarlo llamar para que se muestre en el formulario principal de acuerdo a la pestaña presionada. Aquí el "formulario" de `User control`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar creas un panel, este panel sera comun para cada UserControl que quieras implementar

Dentro del UserControl insertas el siguiente codigo:

```
    // Creo una propiedad UserControl
    private static TuUserControl _istance;
    // Encapsulo esa propiedad que vamos a llamar desde el Form padre
    public static TuUserControl Istance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_istance == null)
            {
                _istance = new TuUserControl();
            }
            return _istance;
        }
    }
```

Luego en el evento OnClick de tu boton/imagen escribes el siguiente codigo:
            // Compruebo si el panel tiene ya insertado el UserControl

```
        // Pregunto al panel si tiene integrado ya el UserControl que he clickeado
        if (!panel1.Controls.Contains(TuUserControl.Istance))
        {   // Si no lo tiene, lo añado al panel y al ser este comun para todos se formaran unas "capas" de UserControl
            panel1.Controls.Add(TuUserControl.Istance);
            // Hago que el user Control ocupe todo el tamaño posible del panel
            TuUserControl.Istance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            TuUserControl.Istance.BringToFront();
        }
        else
           // Si el UserControl clickeado ya esta en las capas del panel simplemente lo pongo el primero(El que se ve)
            TuUserControl.Istance.BringToFront();
```

Comment: Sí, sí lo sabía, pero yo quiero un sidebar y en lugar de palabras por cada pestaña quiero imágenes. Pero muchas gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Si lo que buscas es hacerlo con UserControls te refieres a este ejemplo https://imgur.com/a/w4JWRmy ? Segun que boton clickeas aparecen X panel

Comment: Exacto, eso es lo que busco, un panel de administrador con sidebar, y depende del botón que clikeé mandar llamar y mostrar el contenido que se hizo por a parte.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta segun lo que realmente buscabas,cualquier cosa comentame si te ha valido

Comment: Perfecto, justo lo que buscaba, muchas gracias. Ahora solamente me puedes comentar el código por favor, si no es mucha molestia. Para saber qué es lo que realiza el mismo, ya que hay instrucciones que no me han quedado del todo claras. Te agradecería bastante la explicación.

Comment: No se si ahora te queda del todo claro, en cualquier dime con que apartado concreto no te aclaras. Un saludo

Comment: Sí, ya me quedó más claro, me funcionó de igual forma así en el código del `Usercontrol`:  `public static UserControl1 Instancia = new UserControl1();`, no sé si sea una buena práctica o no. pero no me dio ningún problema.